# Rmarkdown code style in LaTeX

Tags: r, markdown

I would like my R code in latex to look like the rmarkdown block of codes: Distinct colours for functions and grey background. I pasted my code between \begin{markdown} and \end{markdown}
 But this only works for changing latex text to rmarkdown text. I believe I should like in listings or change the background, codecolours manually.  Is this possible? Or does someone already programmed rmarkdown code block layout already? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You would do well to show us a minimal working example with what you have tried, so that it'll be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Okay. Will add:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listings package has the option `backgroundcolor` to change the background of code chunks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray}]
code block
code block
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Trick to make the area bigger:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor = \color{lightgray},frame=single,framerule=0pt,framesep=10pt]
code block
code block
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can we make the shaded area a little bigger code block?

Comment: @BlackMild updated

Answer (score 1):

To list R code as with `knitr` in Rmarkdown you can use... `knitr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<eval=F>>=
code block
code block
@
\end{document}
```